# How to write a query to see who called who the most in an Access database of phone calls?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a phone bill in Excel that shows all calls made to and from my phone and I imported it into a table in Access 2007.  I want to learn to use Access to do a simple query to determine who I talk to the most.

Say we have Column A (caller) and Column B (person being called), and that my number will always be in either column.  How do I make a query in Access to determine which phone number I talk the most with?  I've got the Table with the Excel data in it, but I need some step-by-step handholding to learn how to do the query.

In simple english, I want to query all phone calls that contain my number in either column A or column B.  Then, I want to count each unique pair (mynumber + othernumber or othernumber + mynumber should be counted under the same pair).  Then, I want to count/summarize each unique pair to see which pair yields the highest count.

E.g. Go to Create ribbon, click Query Wizard, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the following table :-

```
Column A : Column B
---------:----------
Fred     : 1
Bill     : 2
Fred     : 1
```

You could do a query for example :-

```
SELECT A, B, Count(B) AS CountOfB
FROM Table1
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY Count(B) DESC
```

This would give you :-

```
Column A : Column B : CountOfB
---------:----------:----------
Fred     : 1        : 2
Bill     : 2        : 1
```

The first row would list the most common occurrences of column B and the count would list the number of times that row has been seen.